# Find document with regular expressions in collections related to populate in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, query, schema, aggregate, aggregate-filter

The aim is to filter a collection of documents (Requests) based on the document field from another collection (Patients, Clients, Doctors, and Services), of which there are several references in the source document. To aggregate the data, the populate method is used on the data model of the collection. However, while the filtering of documents from Patients, Clients, Doctors, and Services that meet the condition is performed, this filtering does not propagate to the Requests collection.

This is the expected behavior of the populate method defined in conditional [queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) on the fields to which the populate is applied.

As per the documentation:

> In general, there is no way to make populate() filter **Request** based on
> properties of the (Patients, Clients, Doctors, and Services).
> For example, the below query won't
> return any results, even though (Patients, Clients, Doctors, and Services) is populated.

**Request Model**

```
@Schema()
export class Request {
    _id?: string;
    __v?: number;
    @Prop()
    request_number: string;
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: DBCollections.servicesCollection })
    service_id: Types.ObjectId;
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: DBCollections.pacientsCollection })
    patient_id: Types.ObjectId;
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: DBCollections.customerCollection })
    client_id: Types.ObjectId;
    Prop({ type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: DBCollections.customerCollection })
    referring_doctors_id: string[];
    @Prop()
    status: boolean;
}

export const SolicitudSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Request);

SolicitudSchema.virtual('customer_info', {
    id: false,
    ref: customer_info.name,
    localField: 'cliente_id',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: true
});

SolicitudSchema.virtual('referring_doctors', {
    id: false,
    ref: Client.name,
    localField: 'referring_doctors_id',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: false
});

SolicitudSchema.virtual('servicio', {
    id: false,
    ref: Service.name,
    localField: 'service_id',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: true
});

SolicitudSchema.virtual('info_patient', {
    id: false,
    ref: Patient.name,
    localField: 'patient_id',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: true
});

SolicitudSchema.set("toObject", { virtuals: true });
SolicitudSchema.set("toJSON", { virtuals: true });
```

The query that I try to do and that doesn't work:

```
   const selectFields = {
     request_number: 1,
     request_date: 1,
     service_id: 1,
     patient_id: 1,
     client_id: 1,
     referring_doctors_id: 1,
     status: 1
   };
  
  
   const result = await this.ModelRequest.find({
     status: true,
     application date: {
       $gte: daterange?.start_date,
       $lt: daterange?.end_date,
     },
     $or: [
       { request_number: { $regex: value, $options: 'i' } },
       { "service.service_name": { $regex: value, $options: 'i' } },
       { "referring_doctors.client_name": { $regex: value, $options: 'i' } },
       { "patient_info.patient_name": { $regex: value, $options: 'i' } },
       { "customer_info.customer_name": { $regex: value, $options: 'i' } },
     ]
   }, selectFields)
     .populate(populates.customer)
     .populate(populates.patient)
     .populate(populates.service)
     .populate(populates.referring_doctors)
     .exec();
  
   return result;
```